# How to show text in datatable containg only a single row and extra text should be hide and only show three dotes (text-overflow: ellipsis;)

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

As i show describe in my question and attached image
[image: DAtatable image attached]

Comment: Have u tried , `text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Can you show some code? How do you build your datatable? which options?